# How can i set sentry a alert rule to multiple project?

Tags: sentry

I want to set a alert rule to multiple project.
but I can't find that.

I have multiple projects, and these projects have a multiple environments(e.g. dev, prod).

and I want to create only two alert rules(for dev, prod), and share these alert rules by environments.

Can I do that??